# creating a SIMPLE ui framework for small app

Tags: .net, user-interface

Ok so long time ago I thought of using CAB on one of my small apps I realized quickly it was a HUGE overkill. I'm building a new app now, to give you an idea after the first release it will only go upto 15,000 lines MAX.

The problem is its a slightly complicated system for a bank, half of the software is on the server and the it has to play around with excel automation too, since its small there hasnt been much planning on our business end and our clients are coming up with new fun features every now and then.

So the app is going to be made in .net 2.0. Its going to tabbed, and will only have a toolbar. I was thinking of a simple framework like this:

The tabcontrol will be an ITabView which will take TabPages which are user controls. It can interact with the toolbar with the following interface, I was thinking of a more general command event which will also contain event data about what happened, because mostly the toolbar will handle its own functionality. The toolbar and tabview can then be singleton so they will be accessible from anywhere?

**IToolbar**

+RunCommand(Command:enum)

+CommandEvent

+ShowProgress

**ITabView**

+Tabs : TabPage

**TabPage** :UserControl  {

+Caption

}

Is this kind of design good enough for a small application like mine? Should I use any framework out there that is simple, or is there a better design commonly used in apps like this?

Comment: Can't find question here. What do you want from people?

Comment: Very sorry.. I edited the question...